# Mutilple Facebook buttons with Unique Description and Thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So, I've searched and searched this site before posting this question -- I know there is a lot of facebook like questions -- but I can't find an answer to mine.

I have a page VERY similar to Mashable.com.  They have multiple teaser articles with LIKE buttons next to each.  When you click the LIKE button, you see the article thumbnail, and the article description.

I already have this set-up and it works EXCEPT for the thumbnail and description.  They are wrong or not showing up at all.  How can I make sure these LIKE buttons are pulling the correct thumbnails and descriptions for each of my articles.

(They are not using Open Graph I don't think, because Mashable.com has no facebook meta tags (and even if they did, the meta tags only specify one thumbnail image, and one title, and one link).

Can anyone tell me how to customise the thumbnails and descriptions for each individual news story?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The href in each like button needs to point to the full URL of that article, which needs to have a full set of open graph meta tags.

Run the (article) page through the debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to make sure the correct tags are present and being detected by Facebook's crawler.

The crawler will fall back to using  tags and other non-Open Graph meta tags if there aren't a full set present, but the behaviour in that case isn't easy to debug, especially in relation to the images.

Mashable's like buttons are pointing at page which *do* have open graph meta tags by the way, e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2011%2F10%2F28%2Fsteve-jobs-tributes%2F

Comment: Thank you.  I understand how it works.  Unfortunately facebook has chosen a very convoluted and poor way of implementing their LIKE button.  On the full article page, I still have the main facebook button (to LIKE the entire website) along with the LIKE button for the article.  With only one meta tag set, I am forced to choose which button to have on the site.  Ridiculous.  I don't know why it can't be straight forward where you just enter your image, title, and description in each LIKE button.  I think I will use the old SHARE button.